# Dishwasher part issue: Gasket holder

Tags: dishwasher

I have a Samsung dishwasher (Model: DW80F800UWS/AC). The part holding the gasket in place in the tub is broken and sticking out. Since it was pretty sharp, I pulled it all out.

Turns out that the part is no longer made. Any suggestions on what I can use to fix this?

For reference, the steel inverted 'U' shaped rods that hold the rubber gasket in place. Part number 7 as per this diagram: https://www.appliancepartspros.com/tub-parts-for-samsung-dw80j3020us-aa.html

Edit: Adding the missing part
[image: The part that holds the gasket]

Comment: Perhaps post a photo of the broken part. Another option could be to repair it, rather than replace

Comment: Part #7 appears to be the gasket itself when I look, so a picture of the actual broken part would be most helpful. Basically, you either make one yourself, find a used one that's not broken, or capitulate to the planned obsolescence and buy a new dishwasher. An "inverted U shaped rod" sounds fairly reasonable to make your own, and I'd suggest following that path.

Answer (score 0):

### Use an underwater epoxy putty

1. If your break is along the straight fitting, find a dowel that fits
   snugly into the part of the channel to use a a backing to mold the
   putty around. 
   **Note:** If the break is on the curved part, its going to be a
   tough fix and you should consider just getting a new washer or
   calling someone someone with a pottery background over to help you.
2. Allow the putty do dry, sand, then add a few coats of a high quality out-door rated painting enamel.